# redirect http to https but show index.php?cmd=

Tags: php, apache

I use this code to redirect my site from http to https . It work

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L,R=301]
```

But when i refresh , my url change to :

```
https://example.com/index.php?cmd=
```

Here is my .htacess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 error/404
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?cmd=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L,R=301]
```

How can i fix it . Thanks

(Sorry i can't add tag .htacess ,so i choose php tag)

Comment: What's `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?cmd=$1 [L,NC,QSA]` for?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `apache` tag?

Comment: kabanus .. I really dont know what is it ? tried disabled but still show index.php?cmd=

Comment: Restart the server after removing it.